# Make d3.text run sequentially?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am creting plots using d3.

I am running a loop, and I am calling this function at each iteration:

```
d3.text(filename[data_idx_outer], "text/csv", function(text)
```

As far as I understand, this function is called asynchronously. It is very important however for me, to run this synchronously, because I have to read the files in a specific order.

Therefore, how can I make this function to run sequentially? If not, as I have to do that, what might be any workarounds?

```
    this.cp_redraw = function() {
        if(this._redraw_in_progress)
            return;

        this.cp_setup_svg();

        this.datums = new Array();

        for(data_idx_outer in this.cp_input_files) {
            var myObj = function(obj) {
                return function() {
                    return obj;
                }
            }

            d3.text(filename[data_idx_outer], "text/csv", function(text){
                data = d3.csv.parseRows(text);
                self.datums.push(data);
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use an `async` library such as Mike Bostock's own `queue` located at https://github.com/mbostock/queue.

```
var q = queue(1);
tasks.forEach(function(t) { q.defer(t); });
q.awaitAll(function(error, results) { console.log("all done!"); });
```